# Rails Rspec redirection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In the `currency` show view, I have a form which submits data that should be sent by the `currency` controller to the `prediction` controller. However, I get an error before I can get to the `prediction` controller.

The form is defined as:

```
<%=form_for @currency do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Days" %>
    <div id="select_days" >
    <%= f.select(:prediction_days, options_for_select(1..30)) %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Predict", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The controller has the following code(the print is executed, then an error occurs).

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @currency.update(currency_params)
        prediction = @currency.neural_network.predict
        p "getting prediction"
        redirect_to prediction
```

The error is:

```
Failure/Error: click_button 'Predict'
     ActionController::UnknownFormat:
       ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

The failure occurs when I am testing with RSpec and Capybara in this manner:

```
click_button 'Predict'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you've got all that code in a `respond_to` block when you're not defining a format. The error seems to address that: `ActionController::UnknownFormat`, because you don't have a format defined (as far as I can see, since your `update` method isn't complete).

Do you really need the `respond_to`? If not, try this:

```
def update
  if @currency.update(currency_params)
    prediction = @currency.neural_network.predict
    redirect_to prediction
  end
end
```

If you do need it, I would suggest setting a format (I'm guessing you've got more formats when you need it):

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      if @currency.update(currency_params)
        prediction = @currency.neural_network.predict
        redirect_to prediction
      end
    end

    format.json { ... } # or whatever format you want to define.
  end
end
```